# Terminology: why "floating multiply-add" instead of "fused multiply-add"?

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer, terminology, fma

C11 (and newer):

> 7.12.13 Floating multiply-add

IEEE 754-2008:

> fused multiply add,
> `fusedMultiplyAdd`

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation):

> fused multiply-add

Why C11 (and newer) uses "floating multiply-add" instead of "fused multiply-add"?

Where this "floating" comes from?

Comment: Because the IEEE-754 committee pays close attention to floating-point wording and the C committee does not to the same degree.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ... and isn't it so that C doesn't specify IEEE-754 for floating-points? The wording in the standard must be generic enough to be usable for alternative formats too (if my assumption is correct)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: No, 7.12.13 describes the `fma` operation which even the C standard says is performed with rounding “as **one** ternary operation” [emphasis added], meaning that the multiply and the add are fused together into one floating-point operation. Whether it is an IEEE-754 operation or not is irrelevant to this point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, ok, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is most likely a mistake from the technical report which introduced these arithmetic operations to the language

With some detective work we may dig down to the root source of C11's "Floating multiply-add" and identify a discrepancy that very much hints at this naming being just an oversight. [WG14's N1154](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1154.pdf) (*Extension for the programming language C to support decimal floating-point arithmetic*) from 2006 idiomatically describe the operation as a *fused multiply-add* arithmetic operation:

> ### 9 Arithmetic Operations
>
> [...]
>
> ### 9.2 Functions
>
> The decimal floating point operations square root, min, max, **fused
> multiply-add** and remainder, which are defined in IEEE 754R, are
> implemented as *library* functions.

Only to replace (arguably by mistake) *fused* by *floating* in the library synopsis for the associated function prototypes. An oversight arguably easily missed in review of the library synopsis as `f` in the abbreviated `fmad` names in the containing function prototypes could easily be misinterpreted as "floating" as opposed to its actual meaning "fused".

> ### 10 Library
>
> #### 10.1 Decimal mathematics <math.h>
>
> The list of elementary functions specified in the mathematics library
> is extended to handle decimal floating-point types. These include
> functions specified in 7.12.4, 7.12.5, 7.12.6, 7.12.7, 7.12.8, 7.12.9,
> 7.12.10, 7.12.11, 7.12.12, and 7.12.13
>
> [...]
>
> **Suggested changes to C99:**
>
> Add the following list of function prototypes to the synopsis of the
> respective subclauses:
>
> [...]
>
> **7.12.13 Floating multiply-add**
>
> ```
> _Decimal64 fmad64(_Decimal64 x, _Decimal64 y, _Decimal64 z);
> _Decimal32 fmad32(_Decimal32 x, _Decimal32 y, _Decimal32 z); 
> _Decimal128 fmad128(_Decimal128 x, _Decimal128 y, _Decimal128 z);
> ```